# "Insofar" or "in so far"

Tags: etymology, expressions

A quick search suggests that *insofar* is the American variant of the British *in so far*. I always assumed it belonged to the set of expressions like *hitherto*, *heretofore*, *therefore* and *albeit*. Is there a preferred usage, and does it matter? General context for the usage of these expressions would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insofar):

> The form insofar is American English; the standard form in British and other English is 'in so far'.

I also have never seen the form 'in so far' used in American English.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "insofar" is restricted to American English - for example this (British) dictionary lists it (and doesn't note it as American, unlike for "traveler/traveller" for example): http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/insofar-as

Comment: I can't speak to whether or not it is acceptable British English; I do know that 'insofar' is the accepted American English version and 'in so far' is not.

Comment: I always knew it was `in so far` in American english as well. Well it explains I am not native American english speaker :)

Answer (score 3):

I am from USA. where insofar is prevailing. I actually haven't encountered "in so far" at all.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of context using *insofar as* or *insofar that*. It seems to be a wordy way to say *since* or *because of*  For example:  Insofar as we received 24 inches of snow, people are advised to limit their driving as much as possible.

Comment: There are ways to use it that are meaningful, in which "since" or "because" would not do. "Hitler's war was successful in so far that he conquered Germany's nemesis; but he failed in his personal quest, that for eternal glory." "Israel's power will be secure only in so far as it is able to protect its current territory: any loss of land is a nail in its coffin, limiting its potential for agriculture and construction."

Comment: @Cerberus, agreed. A better periphrase would be "to the extent that".