# "as far as" vs. "so far as" vs. "in so far as"

Tags: word-choice, formality, comparisons, register, so-vs-as

Are these sentences the same?

1. As far as I know, he's going to Chicago.
2. So far as I know, he's going to Chicago.
3. In so far as I know, he's going to Chicago.

I think that they are the same in meaning but differ in formality.  I think the first one is formal, the second one is informal, and the third one is very formal.

Comment: _So far as I know_ is slightly marked, as formal, in US English. Therefore less common in speech. _Insofar as_ (with variable spacing) is a technical legal term. Don't use it if you aren't a lawyer.

Comment: @JohnLawler why is _insofar as_ specifically legal? It is archaic I grant you, but exclusively legal? Could you provide some references for that?

Comment: As far as popular registers*, _`archaic`_ = _`legal`_; any distinction would be important only to a lawyer or an historian.

Comment: * as far as they go, that is.

Answer (score 3):

> As far as I know, he’s going to Chicago.
>
> So far as I know, he’s going to Chicago.

These are identical in meaning and register. They differ only by dialect or individual speaker preference. According to Google Ngrams, they are approximately equal in popularity:

[image: Google Ngram chart showing relationship between *as far as*, *so far as*, and *in so far as*.]

> In so far as I know, he’s going to Chicago.

This is a less popular variant, which to my ear sounds slightly more formal simply because it’s wordier. In American English [the spelling is *insofar*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8023/insofar-or-in-so-far), meaning “to such an extent”.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the most common usage in casual and even semi-formal speech/writing.