# In 'inasmuch', what did 'in', 'as', 'much' mean?

Tags: etymology, middle-english

> [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93176#eid755936) **inasmuch** {adverb} =     [Etymology:]
>   originally 3 words ***in as much*** (in northern Middle English *in als mikel*), subsequently sometimes written as 2 words, *in asmuch*, and now (especially since 17th cent.) as one.
>
> †3. **in as much** (Without *as* [afterwards])
>   = [4.] In an equal or like `degree`, likewise. (Obs[olete].)

(TL;DR) To  parse **inasmuch**, I consider its original form as 3 separate words, per above.

1. Which do the 3 separate words (***in as much***) mean  individually? Which definitions from OED match each word? OED is linked here for your convenience: [in](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=in&_searchBtn=Search),
[as](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307?rskey=bFp1yM&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid), [much](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123133?rskey=mtgwpV&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid).

2. How did the bolded 3 morphemes combine to mean definition 4? For example, 3 contains no word that  means `degree` in definition 4.   So whence did `degree` originate?

Please expose and explain all hidden, missing semantic drifts.
I read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8023/50720), but wish to dig deeper.

---

Guesswork and Optional Reading (Please feel free to ignore this):

'Equate terms' in 3 and 4 above. Then:

5. **as** appears to equate to 'equal or like'. But this equalisation appears false, because **as** cannot be an adjective, while 'equal or like' is an adjective (phrase). So which definition of [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307?rskey=mzO7D1&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid) matches **as**?

6. **much** appears to equate to`degree`. But this is false, because **much** must be a determiner or  pronoun, while `degree` is a noun. So what did **much** mean here?

Comment: ***Insofar as*** I can see, this question is ***just like*** so many others ***inasmuch as*** it is tries to look too hard for the simple answer which just pops out ***in that*** those are all effectively synonyms. Don’t let the spacing distract you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise is wrong:  "much" doesn't have to be a determiner or a pronoun.  It may be an adverb, meaning "approximately," as the *OED* notes, "[c]hiefly qualifying expressions denoting similarity."

Comment: Sorry, but it’s unclear to me how this answers my question. Even if **much** is an adverb, then how does **much** compare with `degree`?

Comment: @LePressentiment "Compare with degree" is just something you made up.  "As" means like; "much" means approximately; "inasmuch" means in the circumstances approximately equal to that which follows the next "as."

Comment: Thanks. 1. Can you please cite which OED definition supports your writing that `"As" means like`? 2. You wrote `circumstances` above, but where is `circumstances` reflected in **inasmuch**? Notice that the definition above excludes **as**; I just wish to focus on **inasmuch**.

Comment: 1. A.II.3 or B.I.1 2. That's what the "in" means. 3. "inasmuch" is always paired with "as," so your focus is out of.

Comment: Thanks again. 1. From [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307?rskey=elPndp&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid), A.II.3 refers to the adverb, but B.1.1 refers to the conjunction. So how can **as** mean both here? 2. How does 'in' mean `circumstances`? 3. Usually, but not the older adverb above (OED above excludes the `as`) 4. Also, to which definition do you refer for **much** in your answer above? No entries on [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123133?rskey=mtgwpV&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) match your quote.

Comment: And B.I.1 refers to A.II.3 for its sense.  Nothing "means" a part of speech.  "In" means in something, and that something will be found on the other side of the stand-alone "as."  So "inasmuch as *you're on a fool's errand,* means in circumstances like your errand.

Comment: Thanks again. Inasmuch as I'm on a fool's errand, were you able to answer 4 in my comment above, please? I find that your comments have already enlightened me on this adverb.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but would you please be able to  integrate all your comments into your answer, and then delete the integrated comments to avoid confusion by future readers?

Comment: @LePressentiment Inasmuch as time permits.

Comment: Thanks. I acknowledge the time already expended in answering this question, but I thank you effusively in advance and hope for your additional help.